# Is it possible to link two hashes in redis

Tags: redis

I am new to redis and while reading some tutorials , i couldnt found anything about foreign keys , so is it possible to link two hashes like , for eg. linking account hash to person hash?

If possible please give a detailed example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Redis is a key-value store and has no notion of joins.  If you need two pieces of separate but logically connected data your choices are:

1. Change your data structure so all the data is held in a single hash
2. Fetch the parent item, get the id of the child item, then fetch the child item
3. As with 2, but do it in Lua to avoid doing 2 round-trips to Redis